# Error en CreateInstance en Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

He actualizado un proyecto que tenía hecho en visual studio 2013 a visual studio 2019 Comunity.

El proyecto es un proyecto de consola.

Este proyecto tiene el target con framenwork 4.8 y desde entonces al hacer el CreateInstance me da error de ...

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'No se pudo recuperar el generador de clases COM para el componente con CLSID {8682C90E-4E70-4969-B0DB-9D9D68632DE8} debido al siguiente error: 80040154 Clase no registrada (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).'

Este es el trozo de código que me falla.

```
Type OleType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("icuscc.Insertar");
dynamic miObjeto = Activator.CreateInstance(OleType);
```

La librería la tengo registrada y está ubicada en c:\windows\syswow64.
Es una librería de 32bits y mi windows es Windows 8.1 de 64 bits.

Alguna pista?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pregunta relacionada en SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1496214/3613462

Answer (score 0):

Pues finalmente lo he resuelto configurando la aplicación para que sea de 32bits.

Gracias al comentario de Fredyfx que me puso este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496214/how-to-solve-com-exception-class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040)

Os adjunto la captura de pantalla donde he tocado.

[image: donde he cambiado a 32bits]

Gracias a todos